# Getting a RedisException connection refused in file PhpRedisConnector.php

Tags: laravel, redis, predis, laravel-sail

I have pulled an existing laravel project that utilizes sail and Redis. The project acts as an HTTP API. The problem shows it self when im trying to hit one of the endpoints from Postman, I can see that the backend accepts the request and closes again, but I keep getting the same response in postman.

The reponse i keep getting is:
`RedisException: Connection refused in file /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php on line 153`

I have tried changing the APP_URL in my .env file, tried changing the REDIS_HOST in the .env file both times nothing changed, I keep getting the same response.

Keep in mind this is the first time im working with laravel, sail and Redis.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is a link to the docker-compose.yml file content[docker-compose.yml file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1m6g.jpg)

Comment: What did you change `REDIS_HOST` to?

Comment: @apokryfos I have tried a couple of things, `localhost, localhost:6379, http://127.0.0.1, http://127.0.0.1:6379 and redis.`  All in the .env file.

I have also tried a couple of different addresses in postman. I have tried `http.//0.0.0.0` as it is what is displayed the development server is started as. I have tired `http:127.0.0.1` and both give the same result, I can see that the request is accepted and afterwards closed.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you using the default sail docker-compose.yml file? Can you share it if you modified it?

Comment: Im unsure if it is the defualt docker-compose.yml file contnet, but I have updated the questoin with a link to imgur with the fileconent. I hope that it is fine.

Comment: the redis host you would be using for that should be `redis` . If that does not work try checking the redis log files i.e. using `docker-compose logs redis`

Comment: Thanks I will try that and get back with the results.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion using `docker-compose logs redis` as just using `redis` as the `REDIS_HOST` in the .env file did not do the job. 

Here is the results of running the `docker-compose logs redis` [docker-compose logs redis output](https://imgur.com/d4lfnVi) The only problem I can see is the warning about the missing config file.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? is it something to do with the firewall for that port maybe ?